# Availability Group replica failover connection issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, windows-clustering

I uploaded a video explaining what happens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDuRxJAdsLw&feature=youtu.be

When I first try to connect to the failover replica SQL02 under the availability group connection in SQL server management studio, SQL server management studio is unable to connect to SQL02, I have to press options in the connection dialog in order for it to pick the correct port, in my case 1433. So, what port is it trying to connect to? Why does this happen and I have to press options to fix this?

SQL server 2016 with CU2 installed.
Windows server 2016 as well.
SQL server management studio 17.1.

I understand very well that this can be achieved under the failover console, but I am wondering why the management studio is behaving this way. Suppose the default port for this replica server was 1434, what would I do then?

Answer (score 0):

> , I have to press options in the connection dialog in order for it to pick the correct port, in my case 1433

I assume you are trying to connect to one of the instances under an availabilty group,but it connects only when you provide port number..

I believe this issue seems to be with SQLBrowser service.SQL Browser service runs and monitor incoming connections and redirects them to appropriate instances.First check whether this service is on..

Normally you don't need SQLBrowser service,unless you have one or more instances running on the same box..

Try check if sql server browser service status

Comment: I have to click options in order for this port to appear after the server\instance name, and yes the service is running, shouldn't it be able to resolve that one, in the video you could see the instance was in resolving state before i even reached the connect.